# How to trigger an event on an input field using Javascript so that it stores the value and doesn't delete it when clicking submit?

Tags: javascript, html, selenium-webdriver, ui-automation

I am working on a selenium automation script where I am trying to set the value of an input field to one of the values of the </li/> elements that exist within the dropdown.
The issue is that the attributes are stuck within a shadowroot so I have to use the javascript executor to interact with the elements and unfortunately just setting the value = to "1 year" doesn't actually store the value properly.
The webpage will ask for the input to be filled in and won't register the input field has being "filled" in.

On another input field I was able to use .dispatchEvent(new Event('input',{'bubbles':true})); and .dispatchEvent(new Event('change')); in order to trigger the dropdown to appear so that I could select the value I wanted.

However, on this input field it does not seem to work at all. Are there other dispatchEvents I can use?

This is what I'm currently trying to use:

```
document.querySelector("element").shadowRoot.querySelector("input").value = "1 year";

document
  .querySelector("element")
  .shadowRoot.querySelector("input")
  .dispatchEvent(new Event("input", { bubbles: true }));

document
  .querySelector("element")
  .shadowRoot.querySelector("input")
  .dispatchEvent(new Event("change"));
```

The element is an input field however if you click on it a </ul/> dropdrown with </li/> items will appear. I can only seem to get this to appear when I click on it with my actual mouse.

Comment: "The value just disappears after the form is submitted."" - unless the submit is intercepted and canceled by script code, form submission loads a completely new page or frame.  All state from the old page is gone even if it is a postback to the same URL

Comment: @DaveS what I meant to say was that the "1 year" value will appear in the input field but the webpage won't "see" it. It will still think the input field needs a value to be entered

Comment: that event type should be whatever the listener is listening for, probably click but maybe mousedown., mouseup.. I would consider switching to playwright which can query shadow dom

Comment: @pguardiario I unfortunately am restricted to using strictly the JavaScript executor for now but I will look into playwright for future use. Is there a way to figure out the specific element that needs to be interacted with? There is an input field but since it's a drop-down it also has a series of nested divs with a span, I and svg. If I can't cause the value to be registered by the page, maybe I can force the drop-down to open some how

Comment: Yes there's an Event Listeners section when you inspect things (Elements panel) but it's hard to make sense of